# Put Django site in sub directory of another django site

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

The site runs fine at local host but when I go to `localhost/site2` it just loads the 404 page for the root Django site.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        #site1.com
        #ServerAlias www.site1.com
        ErrorLog /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/django-error-log
        Alias /static/ /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1/mainapp/static/
        Alias /media/   /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1/media/
        WSGIDaemonProcess site1 python-path=/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1:/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup site1
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1/site1/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess site2 python-path=/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site2:/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup site2
        WSGIScriptAlias /site2 /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site2/site2/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site2>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1:var/www/virutalenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/var/www/virutalenv-2.7/site2:
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/virtualenv-2.7
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you are configuring 2 sites when you should configure 1 site with two subfolfers (that are different pages). But the site is the root and it is only one

Comment: @HoapHumanoid and how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more thought. What do you really need is *conditional* config. It is possible in Apache 2.4 (sad but not in 2.2),  using `<If>` statement ([docs here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if))

So your config will be transformed to something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        #site1.com
        #ServerAlias www.site1.com
        ErrorLog /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/django-error-log




<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ ^/site1">
        Alias /static/ /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1/mainapp/static/
        Alias /media/   /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1/media/

        WSGIDaemonProcess site1 python-path=/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1:/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup site1
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1/site1/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</If>
<Else>
        Alias /static/ /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site2/mainapp/static/
        Alias /media/   /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site2/media/

        WSGIDaemonProcess site2 python-path=/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site2:/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup site2
        WSGIScriptAlias /site2 /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site2/site2/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site2>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</Else>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have not system with apache 2.4 to test , so possibly can miss something.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot run two sites or django applications inside a single `VirtualHost` this configuration is faulty.

You will need two different virtual host to do that, like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site1.com
        ServerAlias www.site1.com
        ErrorLog /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/django-error-log-from-site1

        Alias /static/ /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1/mainapp/static/
        Alias /media/   /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1/media/

        WSGIDaemonProcess site1 python-path=/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1:/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup site1
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1/site1/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site1>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site2.com
        ServerAlias www.site2.com
        ErrorLog /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/django-error-log-from-site2

        Alias /static/ /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site2/mainapp/static/
        Alias /media/   /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site2/media/

        WSGIDaemonProcess site2 python-path=/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site2:/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup site2
        WSGIScriptAlias /site2 /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site2/site2/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/site2>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you are testing this out on your local system then depending on your OS you may need to do of the following configuration for trying it out.

1. In Windows:  `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`
2. In Linux/Mac: `/etc/hosts`

In this file append the following lines:

```
127.0.0.1 site1.com
127.0.0.1 site2.com
```

If you are using domain name then make there `A Records` point to the required server IP.

Now when you will open `site1.com` in your browser first VH configuration will be used and likewise for `site2.com` when type it as the URL.

Comment: I want to use the same domain name. Site 1 is `site1.com` and Site 2 is `site1.com/site2`

Comment: @User that cannot be done; two django projects cannot run on same domain, all you can do is create a URL in your `site1.com` app and when user opens it, you can `HttpRedirect("http://site2.com")`.

Comment: Then please edit your answer to reflect that it cannot be done.

Comment: @User if you will read the first line of my answer very carefully it says so **You cannot run two sites or django applications inside a single VirtualHost this configuration is faulty.**

Comment: But it doesn't say they can't be the same domain.

Comment: Also, your setup gives the warning `[warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence`

Comment: @User no problems it will work, if you are looking for complete configuration may be you should also take a look at: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html be sure to read the docs specific to your apache version.